# Making std::vector local in templated function results in compilation failure

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

I was playing with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6};

template <template <typename, std::size_t> class S>
S<int, std::dynamic_extent> GetSpan()
{
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = GetSpan<std::span>();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is [accepted](https://godbolt.org/z/31s3fW8f3) by both GCC and Clang. However, if I make `std::vector` local in in function `GetSpan()`, i. e

```
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class S>
S<int, std::dynamic_extent> GetSpan()
{
    std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    return v;
}
```

Clang still [accepts](https://godbolt.org/z/154do6ajK) the code, but gcc rejects it.
Which compiler is right here and why?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour because the `std::vector` object is destroyed before the function returns, so the `std::span` will point to deallocated memory. (Technically derefencing elements from the span will result in UB)

Comment: I don't know which one is right by the standard, but GCC's is the behavior I want (at least in this case).   Since `std:::span` doesn't own the underlying resources, you're likely to encounter undefined behavior.

Comment: Please try to make your questions self-contained. If you get build errors then please include them in the question itself.

Comment: It is interesting though, it seems gcc converts the return value to a temporary, and temporary containers are not convertible to span.

Comment: @chrysante So technically If we try dereferencing elements from the span then we get UB, but what if we don't, is this code still UB?

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan I'm not sure if it's really UB to return the span. I don't think so, because in the end it's simply a pointer that has been deallocated. So if it's not UB, it's at least totally useless.

Comment: If you don't dereference them, it means it's an unused variable. Unused variables are a programming error to me.

Comment: fwiw, `return {v};` makes this work with **g++** (13.1.0).

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not compile in C++23 mode. This is because of a simplified implicit move when returning variables. (See: [cpppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters), [P2266R3](https://wg21.link/P2266R3))

```cpp
    std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    return v;
```

is the same as

```cpp
    std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    return std::move(v);
```

... And a `std::span<int>` cannot be constructed from an rvalue vector.

The previous behaviour was to try to move, and if that move wasn't possible it would copy instead.

It seems that gcc does the simplified move even in C++20 mode.

One of these would fix it:

```cpp
    return (std::vector<int>&) v;
    return static_cast<std::vector<int>&>(v);  // (This seems like the recommended solution)
    return static_cast<decltype((v))>(v);
    return static_cast<decltype(v)&>(v);
    return std::identity{}(v);

    // These two may have slightly different behaviour depending on
    // the constructors of the return type, but work here
    return { v };
    return S<int, std::dynamic_extent>(v);
```

Comment: I don't get how the suggestion fixes the issues.  You are still binding to a function local object that will be destroyed.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike I was assuming this question was about why it doesn't compile ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/76737907#comment135287986_76737907 ). Yes the span can't be accessed, but that it doesn't compile in C++23 is surprising if you didn't know about the implicit move

Comment: Remember, answers aren't just for the OP, they are for everyone.  saying "this is how you fix it" could lead a lot of people to think I just need to do this to get rid of the pesky error and all would be good.  It would be better IMHO to say these techniques can remove the error, but they wont get rid of the issues that the returned span is unusable since it points to an object that no longer exists.

Comment: clang says something else: https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8c3Bhbj4KI2luY2x1ZGUgPHZlY3Rvcj4KCgp0ZW1wbGF0ZSA8dGVtcGxhdGUgPHR5cGVuYW1lLCBzdGQ6OnNpemVfdD4gY2xhc3MgUz4KUzxpbnQsIHN0ZDo6ZHluYW1pY19leHRlbnQ+IEdldFNwYW4oKQp7CiAgICBzdGQ6OnZlY3RvciB2ezEsMiwzLDQsNSw2fTsKICAgIHJldHVybiB2Owp9CgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKICAgIGF1dG8geCA9IEdldFNwYW48c3RkOjpzcGFuPigpOwogICAgcmV0dXJuIDA7Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp20&std=cpp20&rev=1.0